# Terminator display getting messed up

Tags: 14.04, command-line, terminator

I'm using terminator on Ubuntu 14.04. Whenever I open a new tab on it, the graphics of almost all tabs become clumpsy one after other:

[image: Image after opening a tab]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably mean **terminal**, right?  :-D

Comment: No. It's Terminator.

Comment: @Stormlord: [Terminator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(terminal_emulator)) is the name of some specific terminal emulator…

Comment: Are you running this in a VM?

Comment: @DanaHolt :  No. It's not in VM.